# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'get_dummes'

Tags: python, pandas

I follow documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html and I would like to create dummies using `get_dummes()`
My code:

```
mydf.get_dummes(mydf, columns = ['payment_id'])
```

but I get an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_dummes'`. I use pandas 1.3.4. Why?

Comment: There is typo, need `pd` like `pd.get_dummes(mydf, columns = ['payment_id'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it supposed to be `get_dummies()`. There is a typo in your method